# Netty does not handle multiple messages at once

Tags: java, netty

During the tests on your server "nety" I was faced with an unpleasant problem.
I emulate the situation where communication is very poor, and two packets arrived simultaneously.

The server must process the packets as follows:

```
 income binary packet
    |
  transcription packet into my POJO Message class object (objects if few messages in one packet found)
    |
  filtering unexpected messages
    |
  do Logic on every message
```

But when two messages are found in one income packet, only first is processed.

Decoder that transcripts income bytes to Message type

```
 public class InboundDecryptor extends ByteToMessageDecoder { 
  @Override
protected void decode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf in, List<Object> out) throws Exception {
    //      identified =false;
    ArrayList<Message> results = new ArrayList<>();
    byte[] byteinput = new byte[in.readableBytes()];
    in.readBytes(byteinput);
    Message lastIncome = ctx.channel().attr(Server.getLastIncomeKey()).get();
    LOG.debug("RawIncome: " + Message.bytesToHex(byteinput) + "\nlength: " + byteinput.length);
    ArrayList<byte[]> packets = PacketGet.getBytePackets(byteinput);

    if (packets != null & !packets.isEmpty()) {  //send packets to decryption
        for (byte[] packet : packets) {
            byte[] decrypted;
            decrypted = ctx.channel().attr(Server.cypherattrkey).get().decrypt(packet);
            LOG.debug(("bytesIn:" + Message.bytesToHex(decrypted)));
            Message message = PacketGet.toMessage(decrypted);
            if (message != null) {
                LOG.debug(message.toString());
                if (checkNumber(message, ctx, out)) {

                    out.add((Object) message); //send packets to further managing
                } else {
                    skipDC = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (out.isEmpty() && !skipDC) {
        skipDC = false;
        LOG.debug("Nothing was parsed");
        ctx.close();
    }

}
```

The next is filter that process messages and throw away unexpected.

```
 public class ResponseHandler extends MessageToMessageCodec<Message, Message> {

 @Override
protected void decode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Message msg, List<Object> out) throws Exception {
//throw away unexpected messages
//put correct messages into out
  }
}
```

And finally handler that performs logic

```
public class HandlePackets extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler {

@Override
public void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object message) throws Exception {
//doing logic
}
```

Why, when few messages coming simultaneously, only one is processed?
Maybe it's because of two decoders that stays one after another?

**UPD**
I wrote loggin for message handling, and now i can say, that second message do not go into second decoder.

Comment: Can you clarify your "when two messages come in one packet" statement? Do you mean that in your InboundDecryptor.decode method the `ByteBuf in` contains the contents for what will be 2 objects? Can show how you are building your pipeline and the code which translates the ByteBuf into Objects which go into the `List<Object> out`?

Comment: ok, i will update my question.

And yes, i tried to describe situation when parsing one message will result two objects;

Comment: Does the `RawIncome` debug statement print out all the data you expect?  What does `PacketGet.getBytePackets(...)` do and does it return what you expect?  How about `bytesIn` debug output?  Based upon your issue description it sounds like the problem is in this method turning the bytes into objects, but your description is limited so its hard to say.

Comment: Also it seems like you are decryption the data manually. Now when you say decryption is this an SSL decryption or a proprietary decryption? Is there a reason why you can't use add an SslHandler to the pipeline to do the decryption for you.  See this [example](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/master/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/http/file/HttpStaticFileServerInitializer.java#L38).

Comment: Client will be based on controller which can't use SSL and also SSL is to heavy. I using proprietary encryption.
All my debug outputs are allright. Parser works fine. At the end of method i have 2 correct objects in "out" list. But next codec receives only first one.

Comment: There are a lot of pieces where there are no details provided.  Would you be able to provide a reduced set of code that demonstrates the issue?